# harmonic mean for nested list the contains some negative values

Tags: python-3.x

I have to find the harmonic mean of the nested list that contains some negative values. I know `harmonicmean` is only used for positive values, so what can I do to compute harmonic mean of my list?

I tried this:

```
x=[['a', 1, -3, 5], ['b', -2, 6, 8], ['c', 3, 7, -9]]  

import statistics as s
y=[s.harmonicmean(i[1:]) for i in x1]
```

but I get `statistics.statisticserror` for the negative values.

Comment: do you mean `x` instead of `x1` in your list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

`filter` will iterate over a copy of a list, or anything that's iterable, while filtering out elements that don't satisfy a specific condition. Keep in mind I said "copy;" it doesn't mutate the iterable you pass to it.

for example:

```
>>> numbers = [-1, 2, 3]
>>> filter(lambda i: i >= 0, numbers)
[2, 3]
```

or if you just want absolute values, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) which will iterate over a copy of a list, or anything that's iterable, while applying a function to each element:

```
>>> map(abs, numbers)
[1, 2, 3]
```